# When navigating using the Up button, the state of the Parent Activity is not preserved

Tags: android, android-activity, android-navigation

When navigating using the Up button, the state of the Parent Activity is not preserved. The state is preserved perfectly when I use the back button to navigate to the Parent Activity. Is this the intended behavior? If not, what step am I missing to make the Parent Activity preserve its state (the text in EditTexts, for example)?

Comment: How are you implementing the up button's functionality in your app? Are you just specifying the activity's parent in your manifest?

Comment: I'm specifying the parent as well as adding meta-data about the parent in the manifest. I'm also overriding onOptionsItemSelected() and using: case android.R.id.home:
                NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just looking to save values in the EditText fields, you should look into saving values for the activity into your SharedPreferences.

Alternately, you can always call the 'onBackPressed' method from your Up button. The Up button is handled just like any other action bar icon, so there is a call made to onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item). You just need to check for the case android.R.id.home in the item's id and call the onBackPressed there

Comment: Thanks! So, not preserving state is the intended behavior, and I'm not missing anything?

Comment: As far as I am aware, when doing the standard HomeAsUp behavior, the home button sends a new intent with the class type that you set in the Meta tag in the manifest.

Comment: I tried onBackPressed approach - it's triggered from onOptionsItemSelected but the state is not restored in the calling activity.